# Marker not moving on Google MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I implement google map view inside fragment, everything is working but Marker is not moving into new location its fixed. I tried long press,listeners,tapping on other part of map, Nothing works.

MapView Fragment

```
public class MapLocation_Fragment extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,OnMapReadyCallback {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap google_Map;
    Marker Map_marker;
    LatLng locclPosition;
    double lati,longi;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maplocation_fragment, container, false);
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.send_Location_MapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.onResume();// Needed tog et the map to display immediately

        lati=getArguments().getDouble("lat");
        longi=getArguments().getDouble("longi");
        locclPosition=new LatLng(lati,longi);

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }



    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        Map_marker=marker;

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        google_Map = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }


        google_Map.setOnMarkerClickListener(MapLocation_Fragment.this);
        google_Map.setOnMarkerDragListener(MapLocation_Fragment.this);

        google_Map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        google_Map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        google_Map.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); //THIS OPTION WILL SHOW MAP IN SATELLITE FORM
        google_Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(locclPosition)
                .title("Current Location")
                .draggable(true));
        CameraPosition cameraPosition=new CameraPosition.Builder().target(locclPosition).zoom(19).build();
        google_Map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
}
```

I need to marker to move where ever user tap on map but after lot of effort its still not moving at all. Please help guys.

Comment: I could see your code is gud. Longpress on your marker and try dragging it.

Comment: @YaminiBalakrishnan tried this but no luck

Answer (score 0):

To make your marker move when dragging it you need to write some code in your `onMarkerDragEnd` method, basically to update the position of your marker (`locclPosition`) to where the dragging ends (new coordinates)

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    locclPosition = marker.getPosition();
}
```

Comment: This will work when marker can move but my issue is Map marker is always fixed its not moving at all